# Angular 2 Tour of Heroes HTTP ctorParameters.map is not a function

Tags: angular

I'm trying to complete the HTTP section of the Angular tour of heroes tutorial.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html

After changing app.module.ts from v1 to v2 the application no longer loads and I get the following error in the console:

> dashboard:16 Error: (SystemJS) ctorParameters.map is not a function
>       TypeError: ctorParameters.map is not a function
>           at ReflectionCapabilities.parameters (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:1780:49)
>           at Reflector.parameters (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:1922:48)
>           at CompileMetadataResolver.getDependenciesMetadata (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14534:56)
>           at CompileMetadataResolver.getTypeMetadata (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14499:28)
>           at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14403:30)
>           at eval (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14324:52)
>           at Array.forEach (native)
>           at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14311:46)
>           at RuntimeCompiler._compileComponents (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:17063:49)
>           at RuntimeCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:17001:39)
>       Evaluating http://localhost:3000/app/main.js
>       Error loading http://localhost:3000/app/main.js
>           at ReflectionCapabilities.parameters (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:1780:49)
>           at Reflector.parameters (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:1922:48)
>           at CompileMetadataResolver.getDependenciesMetadata (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14534:56)
>           at CompileMetadataResolver.getTypeMetadata (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14499:28)
>           at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14403:30)
>           at eval (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14324:52)
>           at Array.forEach (native)
>           at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14311:46)
>           at RuntimeCompiler._compileComponents (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:17063:49)
>           at RuntimeCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:17001:39)
>       Evaluating http://localhost:3000/app/main.js
>       Error loading http://localhost:3000/app/main.js

The only difference between the files are the follwing lines:

```
import { InMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
import { InMemoryDataService }  from './in-memory-data.service';
```

I found some answers which point blame with the angular-in-memory-web-api but with a different error and an older version. So based on those answers I figure the following two files may give clues.

here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run lite",
    "lite": "lite-server"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~2.4.0",

    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.16",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2"
  }
}
```

and my systemjs.config.js

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',
      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the angular-in-memory-web-api and it's going to be some sort of config issue. Thankyou.

Comment: I'd assume you're using ctorParameters.map() somewhere in your code?

Comment: Duplicate answer sorted my problem, high level the issue is the same just with different files.